# Securely render arbitrary user-uploaded content (from a WSYWIG editor)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, iframe, xss, content-security-policy

I have a site which allows an admin to edit a section of one page of the site with arbitrary HTML (via a WSYWIG editor), and I want to figure out a way to serve this arbitrary HTML securely to other users.

The basic intent is to eliminate any possibility of XSS errors (i.e, a user getting their cookie stolen or something).
I've seen that the following subset of HTML tags are unsafe to allow users to enter: iframe, frame, embed, style, video, object, etc.
However, filtering out iFrames or style tags is not feasible for my use case because admins need to be able to upload youtube videos and style the text.

I've also heard that Content Management Systems sometimes serve user-uploaded content from a separate domain (e.g, content.mysite.com) so that whatever code may run as a result of the user-uploaded content can't steal my site's cookie (e.g, app.mysite.com) because of the same origin policy.
However, this seems like kind of an overblown solution for me since my site is not a CMS,
there's just one part of one page (editable only by admins) which allows for arbitrary customization.

So, is there a way to go about this?
Would embedding the arbitrary content in an iframe keep users safe? 
Thanks in advance!

Also of potential relevance: the framework I'm using is Ruby on Rails.

Comment: What is a WSYWIG editor?

Answer (score 0):

An html editor on the client is not straightforward to protect against XSS at all. As you say, serving such content from a different domain may mitigate the risk, but gives way to other questions (like for example how will you authenticate and authorize users on the other domain to prevent downloading any user's content).

Also whitelist validation of tags and attributes is usually not feasible. You could have a whitelist of tags and attributes of those tags and anything else could be removed from html code. The problem with this is that the html editor will most likely want to use the style attribute, and styles are vulnerable to XSS, at least in older browsers. An editor usually needs to be able to save a link (`<a href="">`), and that's also vulnerable to XSS, for example `<a href="javascript: alert(1)">`.

One approach you may take and one that actually works is [Google Caja](https://developers.google.com/caja/). It can remove all Javascript from HTML, Javascript and CSS so that it's safe to include in your page. It also has a client-side sanitizer written in Javascript that can be used by itself, and may provide enough protection. Another client-side sanitizer is [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify). Caja at its best is a server-side solution too, but that's somewhat harder to install and maintain. The client-side part of it, and also DOMPurify are slightly less secure as they are all on the client, but can very well provide adequate protection in many situations. (Note that DOMPurify does not work in older browsers and does not sanitize CSS code, which is OK-ish for recent browsers.)

With these client-side solutions, you let the user save any HTML with any injected Javascript to the database if the user (attacker) is smart enough, but when displaying the html content, you send it to the client in a way that's not vulnerable to XSS (like for example in an AJAX response with a text/javascript content type), and then run it through the client-side sanitizer in the browser before inserting into the page DOM (giving it to the editor control itself).

If your editor allows for the right hooks, you can also do this for any preview functionality, sanitizing the HTML entered before switching to preview. This is important, because while arguably a smaller risk, it is still considered XSS if the user can inject Javascript in the editor and then run it in preview, without ever sending it to the server. This is called DOM XSS, and it is one reason you may want to do sanitization on the client.